# what is the string submitted to getting the reusableview in collection view section

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

In collection view section, for getting the particular section we have suplementaryView function. but what is the value should be passed for "forElementKind" ?

```
collectionView.supplementaryView(forElementKind: "???", at: 0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is type of View.

if it is header then you can use `UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader`  or if footer then `UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter`

```
 let indexHeaderForSection = NSIndexPath(row: 0, section: indexPath.section) 
 let heder = collectionViewArea?.supplementaryView(forElementKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, at: indexHeaderForSection as IndexPath ) // you need to pass indexpath instead of integer value.
```

Comment: Thank you, but "at:0" it is asking for IndexPath, not taking 0 value,
am using this one inside a didselct method of collection view.

Comment: i have mentioned about that **you need to pass indexpath instead of integer value**.

Comment: if you used this in didSelect then you need to pass simply NSIndexpath's object **indexPath**.

Answer (score 0):

[image: See the below image Whatever you give identifier you have passed as the parameter as a string]

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    if collectionView == self.collectionCar {
        return UICollectionReusableView()
    }

    let footer = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "PersonFooter", for: indexPath) as! PersonFooter



    return footer
}
```